# Bounds over expected value of reciprocal binomial random variable

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, expected-value

Given a binomial random varible $N \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$, I want to find  an upper bound for the value:

$$\phi \equiv \sup_{n \cdot p \geq 1} \mathbb{E} \bigg( \frac{np}{\max(N,1)} \bigg).$$

(Note that $n,p$ are arbitrary.)  I have proved that $1 \leq \phi \leq 2$.  I think I can show that $\phi=1$, but I am not sure.

**Edit:** Using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E10+%28%28%2810+choose+n%29*p%5E%28n%29*%281-p%29%5E%2810-n%29%29%2Fmax%28n%2C1%29%29%29*10*p-1.3%3D0), it is shown that the supremum is larger than 1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Exploring

Trying out a few values we see that the values get higher for larger $n$.

(we have drawn a red line based on the bound computed below)

[image: example]

```r
f = function(n,p) {
  x = 0:n
  px = dbinom(x,n,p)
  x[1] = 1
  return(sum(px*n*p/x))
}
f = Vectorize(f)
p = seq(0,1,0.001)

plot(-1,-1, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,2),
     xlab = "p", ylab = "E[np/x]")
title("exploring the bound")
for (ni in c(1:10)) {
  lines(p,f(ni*10,p))
}

lines(c(0,1),opt*c(1,1), col = 2)
```

#### Computing/approximating attempt

Based on the above (tendency to high n and small p) we can try and approximate the sum by replacing the binomial distribution with a Poisson distribution with $\lambda = np$

$$f(k) \approx \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$

and [let Wolfram alpha compute](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20k%3D1%20to%20infinity%20%20%28x%2Fk%29%20x%5Ek%2Fk%21%20e%5E-x)

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda}{k} \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{ k!} = -e^{-\lambda}\lambda(log(\lambda)-Ei(\lambda)+ \gamma)$$

We arrive at

$$E[np/k] \approx e^{-np}np(1-log(np)+Ei(np)- \gamma) $$

(where we added an extra term $np e^{-np}$ to capture the contribution of $k=0$)

Maybe this can be differentiated, but I had it computed and arrive at a bound of approximately

$$\phi \approx 1.386317$$

```r
x <- seq(0,6,0.1)
y <- -exp(-x)*x*(log(x)-expint::expint_Ei(x)+0.57721)+x*exp(-x)
plot(x,y)
opt <- max(y, na.rm = TRUE)
opt
### opt = 1.386317
```